# Questions page seems broken when pressed back button on browser

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, new-nav

I was looking [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) questions recently, and clicked on my profile picture to navigate to my profile page. When I clicked on the back button of my browser the questions page showed something like this:

[image: Page Issue]

All the right side contents were gone, all hot posts, ads and everything were missing. I tried the same scenario several times and I got the same result every time.

**Additional Info:**

- OS : Mac OS Yosemite
- Browser : Safari 9.0.1

When this happens, I'm getting the following error on my Web-Browser console:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Can you repro this consistently? If so, what are the steps and what URL do you get in the address bar?

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze: I was in this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios then I switched to my [profile] (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp) and clicked back button of safari browser. And yes, I reproduced it several time, checked now also

Comment: Can you try again and check the console please?

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze: When navigated to profile page, got this error TypeError: winterBashCurrentHats1104384 is not a function. (In 'winterBashCurrentHats1104384({"1104384":{"i":32,"x":16,"y":48,"s":100,"r":0}})', 'winterBashCurrentHats1104384' is undefined)

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze: When navigating back, got `[Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com' failed: Failed to send WebSocket frame.
 t
 onopen
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'L.send')
 t
 onopen` error